# I want the infowindow in my Google map to close automatically when a different icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have used a Snazzy map example and I would like the infowindow to close automatically when another icon is clicked?

I have set up a few variables for markers because I would like each marker to be a different colour.
I then call this each marker var in an info variable which holds the information.

Any help would be greatly received as I am new to web Development.

```
$(function() {
  var mapStyle = [{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#444444"
    }]
  },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f2f2f2"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      },
        {
          "color": "#e6e6e6"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "saturation": -100
      },
        {
          "lightness": 45
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      },
        {
          "hue": "#ff0000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#fd9836"
      },
        {
          "saturation": "85"
        },
        {
          "lightness": "31"
        },
        {
          "gamma": "1.24"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "labels.text",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "hue": "#ff0000"
      },
        {
          "saturation": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.station",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      },
        {
          "hue": "#ff0000"
        },
        {
          "saturation": "-100"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.station.airport",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.station.bus",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.station.rail",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      },
        {
          "hue": "#ff7e00"
        },
        {
          "saturation": "-100"
        },
        {
          "lightness": "19"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#d7d7d7"
      },
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  // Create the map
  var map = new google.maps.Map($('.map-canvas')[0], {
    zoom: 8,
    styles: mapStyle,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.685429, -1.503624)
  });


  var adamDawson = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.992120, -1.541812), //harrogate
    map: map,
    title: 'click for details',
    icon: '../fda_map_2/assets/images/icon_green.png'
  });

  var andrewGomersall = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.792036, -1.539607), //jrc.agency
    map: map,
    title: 'click for details',
    icon: '../fda_map_2/assets/images/icon_dark_green.png'
  });

  var chloeFrank = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.519962, -0.109158), //we make websites
    map: map,
    title: 'click for details',
    icon: '../fda_map_2/assets/images/icon_green.png'
  });

  var darrenSmith = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.716489, -1.640213), //buffalo web design
    map: map,
    title: 'click for details',
    icon: '../fda_map_2/assets/images/icon_orange.png'
  });

  var geniusDivision = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.555143, -1.479377), //geniusdivision
    map: map,
    title: 'click for details',
    icon: '../fda_map_2/assets/images/icon_orange.png'
  });

  // Add a Snazzy Info Window to the marker

  var info = new SnazzyInfoWindow({
    marker: adamDawson,
    content: '<h2>Adam Dawson</h2>' +
    '<p>Freelance Web Designer & Developer</p>' +
    '<a class="work-url" href="http://www.dawsony.com/" target="_blank">Adam Dawson - Web Design & Development</a>',
    closeOnMapClick: true
  });

  var info = new SnazzyInfoWindow({
    marker: andrewGomersall,
    content: '<h2>Andrew Gomersall</h2>' +
    '<p>Lead Developer</p>' +
    '<a class="work-url" href="https://jrc.agency/" target="_blank">jrc.agency</a>',
    closeOnMapClick: true
  });

  var info = new SnazzyInfoWindow({
    marker: chloeFrank,
    content: '<h2>Chloe Frank</h2>' +
    '<p>Front-End Developer</p>' +
    '<a class="work-url" href="https://wemakewebsites.com/" target="_blank">We Make Websites</a>',
    closeOnMapClick: true
  });

  var info = new SnazzyInfoWindow({
    marker: darrenSmith,
    content: '<h2>Darren Smith</h2>' +
    '<p>Web Developer</p>' +
    '<a class="work-url" href="https://www.buffalowebdesign.co.uk/contact/" target="_blank">Buffalo Web Design</a>',
    closeOnMapClick: true
  });

  var info = new SnazzyInfoWindow({
    marker: geniusDivision, //genius div
    content:

    '<div class="genius-wrap">' +
    '<img src="../fda_map_2/assets/images/icon.png">' +

    '<h2>Craig Burgess</h2>' +
    '<p>Creative Director</p>' +

    '<a class="work-url" href="https://www.geniusdivision.com/" target="_blank">Genius Division</a>' +

    '<h2>James Sheriff</h2>' +
    '<p>Business Development Director</p>' +

    '<a class="work-url" href="https://www.geniusdivision.com/" target="_blank">Genius Division</a>' +

    '<h2>Aaron Linley</h2>' +
    '<p>Web Designer / Front-End Developer</p>' +

    '<a class="work-url" href="https://www.geniusdivision.com/" target="_blank">Genius Division</a>' +
    '</div>',
    closeOnMapClick: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    info.open(map,marker);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/antonymoss/70vmsatb/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `closeWhenOthersOpen: true` to the properties of all your SnazzyInfoWindows like I did below.

```
var info = new SnazzyInfoWindow({
  marker: adamDawson,
  content: '<h2>Adam Dawson</h2>' +
    '<p>Freelance Web Designer & Developer</p>' +
    '<a class="work-url" href="http://www.dawsony.com/" target="_blank">Adam Dawson - Web Design & Development</a>',
  closeOnMapClick: true,
  closeWhenOthersOpen: true
});
```

I found that property in the [snazzy info window docs](https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window#closewhenothersopen).

You can test it out in this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivdekov/70vmsatb/27/).

Comment: Hey thank you very much. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help 